# PHP Two Pages of Data for One Class

Tags: php, class

I have one page where the user will enter information about a school assignment (what school it belongs to, what class it belongs to, and the assignment's name).
Next, I have a second page where the user will enter the actual content of the assignment.

I need both sets of data to be passed to one `class` called `AddAssignment`. How do I go about storing the data from the first page along with the data from the second page?

Comment: store in the session?

Comment: store 1st page data in a session, database, or 2nd page form hidden element?

Comment: Thank you so much. I really appreciate it! This is a fantastic idea. Also, thanks to everyone else, great comments!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think in both pages you are using Form to submit and save information.

you can pass data of both pages to one class called AddAssignment.

First page form submit button having name AddAssignmentName and second page's submit button name AddAssignmentContent and these parameter differentiate date when you submitting details from any one of the page then you may perform your other information.